# socketserver module working with command python on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, python, sockets

I'm new to the forum, and I'm writing because I have a strange problem: I wrote a code using socketserver module one or two years ago and if I launch the code with the command "python script.py", it works like a charm without error. Replicating this on a new operating system it gives "no module named socketserver" as I would expect. In the old system pip3 it is not even installed, so, since in my code I use other modules as pigpi (installed with pip), I assume it is running on python 2.7. How can this be possible?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your premise is wrong.  You are assuming pip is the only method to install Python modules.  That is not true.  If they are in the repository they can be installed with apt/dpkg etc.  They may also be pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/ for the naming conventions of Python on Linux systems.

python -> python2 -> python2.7

python3 -> python3.x

So the command "python script.py" will run Python2. In python2 it was `ServerSocket` and in Python3 it is `socketserver` https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html

So from what you have put in your question I would expect it to work if you did "python3 script.py"

So for example:

```
[bash]~ $ python -c 'import socketserver; print(socketserver.__version__)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named socketserver
[bash]~ $ python3 -c 'import socketserver; print(socketserver.__version__)'
0.4
```